# Second-Person Plural Imperative in ברכת קדושת השם of Rosh HashShanah and Yom Kippur

Tags: tefilla, high-holidays

In the expanded 3rd blessing of the Amidah used on the yamim nora'im, there is a sentence (in Nusah Sefard):

לדור ודור המליכו לאל כי הוא לבדו מרום וקדוש

This is phrased in the second-person plural imperative, addressing some plural group and commanding them to do something. How does this make sense in a silent prayer spoken to God?

Comment: not sure that this is sufficient but you can think about yourslelf as a part of the tsibur when you pray silent in a tsibur, or in makom sheyesh chever Ir. and hear for yourself as a part of the tsibur this statement: "ledor vador hamlichu" and you take for yourself this commandment.

Comment: I'm not following your concern on this particular paragraph. Why would this concern you any more than, say, the plural in מודים אנחנו לך when you are the only one giving thanks?

Comment: @Danf, I'm concerned about the implied number of the one(s) being spoken to. Since prayer is usually understood as being addressed to God, the plural seems puzzling. I don't think this comes up in any other paragraph in the Amidah. In מודים אנחנו לך the addressee is singular (לך is singular).

Comment: I believe the version exists (and Wikisource [corroborates](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94), for what it's worth) that has a _chirik_ on the _he_, referring to the antecedent _k'doshim_, who are referred to elsewhere in the arbitrary 3rd person plural.

Comment: @WAF, that's interesting, that would make sense.

Comment: @kouty, I guess that works but would make more sense in a prayer said aloud rather than in the silent prayer.